# Prolog predicate

Tags: prolog, predicate

Hello I am a newbie to Prolog with basic question. I would like to know why these Prolog predicates `daughter_of/2` and `son_of/2` do not work as I want them to. For example, if I ask

```
16 ?- daughter_of(alice, X).
true.
```

(Why true? What predicate would I need to get Victoria and Albert?)

Thank you.

```
male(albert).
male(edward).

female(alice).
female(victoria).

parents(edward, victoria, albert).
parents(alice, victoria, albert).

sister_of(X,Y):-
    female(X),
    parents(X,M,F),
    parents(Y,M,F).

brother_of(X,Y):-
    male(X),
    parents(X,M,F),
    parents(Y,M,F).

daughter_of(X,Y):-
    female(X),
    parents(X,M,F).

son_of(X,_Y):-
    male(X),
    parents(X,M,F).
```

Comment: A `Y` doesn't appear anywhere in the body of your `daughter_of(X, Y)` predicate clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the definition of your doughter_of predicate.

```
daughter_of(X,Y):-
female(X),
parents(X,M,F).
```

It should be

```
daughter_of(X,Y):-
female(X),
parents(X,Y,_).

daughter_of(X,Y):-
female(X),
parents(X,_,Y).
```

So that the Y parameter is passed on to the parents predicate. Otherwise it would not be used (and even gives me a warning when loading the file). Then prolog could only tell you that X is female and X has parents, but the actual parents would be discarded because M and F are no output parameters of your predicate.

Notice that i have defined the daughter_of predicate twice to work with the father as well as with the mother.

The same applies to son_of.

Comment: Hello, and thank you. What do you mean when you say M and F are no output parameters of the predicate? Translating into plain English, X is the daughter of Y if X is female and X's parents are Y and _ (what is __? And has not Y found unification with Victoria? (for the second predicate Y is now asked to unify with something else? (why not give it a new variable?) Thank you again.

Comment: I meant that Y and M / Y and F are never unified. When you call daughter_of(alice, X) you expect the output/result(Victoria and Albert) to be unified with X. So X is your output variable. But Inside your predicate M and F are never unified with Y. M will be unified with the value Victoria. You expect X=Victoria, but X is not unified with M.